# Inserting text into iFrame on page (copy from outside the iframe)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, iframe, pardot

I am trying to pre-fill a form field with a string of text that is on the page. 
But the form is in an Iframe which is making it difficult.

Here is [the page in question](https://idio.ai/thank-you-webinar-testing-ground/) however you will not get much out of the link as the dynamic content for you will be empty. This screenshot might explain better: http://prntscr.com/kbqoak

I tried to put together a Javascript to copy that text over into that form field:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
jQuery(".refer_webinar input").val($('.webinartitle').text());
)
    }
```

It would grab the text from the "webinartitle" class and insert into form field (http://prntscr.com/kbqqp4). But it does not work and I suspect because it is in an iframe.

Can you please help figuring out if there is a way to inject this information in there? (if it's possible)

Answer (score 0):

If in the iframe you can do so ...

```
$(function(){
    $('iframe').contents().find('.refer_webinar input').val($('.webinartitle').text());
    });
```

Comment: thanks for the comment. Unfortunately this does not seem to do anything. here is a screenshot: http://prntscr.com/kbsxa9

Comment: The script needs to be placed outside the iframe

Comment: Ah I see. 
edit: It's not better that way I am afraid: http://prntscr.com/kbtp4u / http://prntscr.com/kbtper 
The value is still not getting there unfortunately.

Comment: any ideas what is wrong here? The above JS still does not work even though it is placed outside of the iframe. @sentimo